# Show / Hide div and still function with content inside - HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have something that "posts" like Twitter. I want this function to be working when "postBox" opens as well. But my current problem is that postBox isn't opening at all.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/julianbuscema/yqh2rqh0/22/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="answer" value="post" onclick="openBox()" />

<div id="postBox" style="display:none;">
<center>
    <input type="text" name="post" maxlength="100" />
    <br>
    </br>
    <button style="border : solid 0px #000080; border-radius : 4px; moz-border-radius : 4px; -webkit-box-shadow : 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0); -moz-box-shadow : 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0); box-shadow : 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0); font-size : 24px; font-style : ;color : #ffffff; padding : 4px 10px; background-color : #000080;">post</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <center>
    <table class="rows"></table>
</center>
</center>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var inpt = document.getElementsByName("post")[0];

function openBox() {
   document.getElementById('postBox').style.display = "block";
}

btn.onclick = function () {

    if (!inpt.value) alert("Please enter something to post.");

    var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var row = tbl.insertRow(0);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var txt = document.createTextNode(inpt.value);
    cell.appendChild(txt);
    tbl.insertRow(0);
    tbl.insertRow(0);

    inpt.value = "";

};
```

Comment: JSfiddles are nice to have, but a complete, minimal code that reproduces the problem needs to be in the question itself for current and future viewers.  Please click the "edit" link below your question to add the code.

Comment: It's working fine for me, whats the issue? [http://jsfiddle.net/yqh2rqh0/25/](http://jsfiddle.net/yqh2rqh0/25/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with how JSFiddle is set up: the openBox function is not at global/window scope:

Change

```
function openBox() {
   document.getElementById('postBox').style.display = "block";
}
```

to

```
window.openBox = function() {
    document.getElementById('postBox').style.display = "block";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yqh2rqh0/33/

Comment: you dont have to do that, just change `onLoad` to `No-Wrap - in <body>` in the sidebar

Comment: that seems more suitable, @jmore009

Answer (score 1):

You chose to run code onLoad in jsFiddle options on the left. Choose `No wrap - in <body>` instead and your code will work.

You can also use `No wrap - in <head>` but it will need some minor changes to work properly (see: http://jsfiddle.net/yqh2rqh0/27/)

Comment: This is a better answer, although I hope this question isn't actually about how to use jsfiddle...